# Typescript declaration file for chessboardjs (implicit import)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, typescript-typings

Hoping to create a few declaration files for DefinitelyTyped (So I want to make sure they are top quality).

The next lib I am taking on is https://github.com/oakmac/chessboardjs/. I actually have it working if I import it like so

```js
// WHAT WORKS
import * as ChessBoard from "chessboardjs";
```

and now i can use the lib by calling

```js
const board = ChessBoard('board1', 'start');
```

The problem is i want the import statement to be implicit (ES6 style) and not sure how to go by doing that

```js
// WHAT I WOULD LIKE
import { ChessBoard } from "chessboardjs";
```

I would like some guidance on how to go by doing this if possible. As I'm still new to typescript and declaration files, maybe the lib just isn't built for implicit imports

This is what i have so far in the index.d.ts file

```js
declare namespace ChessBoardJS {
    interface BoardConfig {
        onDrop?: Function;
        draggable?: boolean;
        onChange?: Function;
        onMoveEnd?: Function;
        onSnapEnd?: Function;
        sparePieces?: boolean;
        onDragMove?: Function;
        showNotation?: boolean;
        onDragStart?: Function;
        onSnapbackEnd?: Function;
        onMouseoutSquare?: Function;
        onMouseoverSquare?: Function;
        pieceTheme?: string | Function;
        orientation?: ChessBoardJS.Types.OrientationType;
        showErrors?: boolean | string | Function;
        moveSpeed?: number | ChessBoardJS.Types.SpeedType;
        snapSpeed?: number | ChessBoardJS.Types.SpeedType;
        trashSpeed?: number | ChessBoardJS.Types.SpeedType;
        dropOffBoard?: ChessBoardJS.Types.DropOffBoardType;
        appearSpeed?: number | ChessBoardJS.Types.SpeedType;
        snapbackSpeed?: number | ChessBoardJS.Types.SpeedType;
        position?: ChessBoardJS.Types.PositionType | string | object;
    }
}

declare namespace ChessBoardJS.Types {
    type PositionType = 'start';
    type PositionFenType = 'fen';
    type SpeedType = 'slow' | 'fast';
    type OrientationFlipType = 'flip';
    type OrientationType = 'white' | 'black';
    type DropOffBoardType = 'snapback' | 'trash';
}

interface ChessBoardInstance {
    clear(useAnimation?: boolean): void;
    destroy(): void;
    fen(): string;
    flip(): void;
    move(...args: string[]): object; // *FIND RETURN*
    position(newPosition: object | string | ChessBoardJS.Types.PositionType, useAnimation?: boolean): void
    position(fen?: ChessBoardJS.Types.PositionFenType): string | object;
    orientation(side?: ChessBoardJS.Types.OrientationType | ChessBoardJS.Types.OrientationFlipType): string;
    resize(): void;
    start(useAnimation?: boolean): void;
}

interface ChessBoardFactory {
    (containerElOrId: any, config: ChessBoardJS.BoardConfig): ChessBoardInstance
    fenToObj(fen: string): any;
    objToFen(obj: any): any;
}

declare var ChessBoard: ChessBoardFactory;
declare module "chessboardjs" {
    export = ChessBoard;
}
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Hey, just wondering-- did you make any further progress on the typings for this library?

Comment: I think I did. I have not pushed it to definitelyTyped yet though. I can share it with you in the mean time if you are also working on something similar

Comment: I'm working on something that would greatly benefit from the typings for chess and chessboard. You can reach me at rikkigibson at gmail dot com. (Sorry, didn't see any other means to convey contact info.)

Comment: Np. i will have them in your email in a few min

Comment: https://github.com/Sliverb/angular-firebase-chess/tree/master/src/typings

You actually also get them here also

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like this. The definition file *describes* how the library works.

This

```
import * as ChessBoard from "chessboardjs"
```

and this

```
import ChessBoard from "chessboardjs"
```

and this

```
import { ChessBoard } from "chessboardjs"
```

each mean three very different things at runtime. Almost certainly only one of them works. If you have a working import, you shouldn't be touching the definition file at all. It's just going to break at runtime.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. As the author of the definition file, I assumed I had some flexibility around how I structured it as long as it described the Lib at the end.
I apologize for my noobness, I'm still in learning mode. Is it safe to assume the flexibility doesn't extent to the import/export styles?