# Creating Javascript object from Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create a javascript object from Typescript.

This is the Javasript object I am trying to create:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chess.js/0.10.2/chess.js

In the javascript sample, you just create the object like this:

```
this.engine = new Chess();
```

How do I do this in Typescript?

I imported the object like this (I downloaded the file and added it to my project):

```
import * as Chess from './../chess.js';
```

However, if I try to create a Chess object I get a build error:

```
const engine = new Chess();
```

Error says: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.

Comment: At least related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687779/how-do-you-produce-a-d-ts-typings-definition-file-from-an-existing-javascript

Comment: Are you using a type definition file (.d.ts) for the referenced script ?

Comment: *"Creating Javascript object from Typescript"* You don't have "JavaScript objects" and "TypeScript objects," you just have objects. TypeScript compiles (transpiles) to JavaScript. What you're lacking is a type definition file (`*.d.ts`) for the JavaScript library you want to use which tells TypeScript the types of the things in that library.

Comment: Potentially related as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437964/typescript-declaration-file-for-chess-js

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your responses. I did a lot of digging into the different methods and I found this just might work.

```
npm install --save chess.js
```

This creates a node module for `chess.js`.

From there I can create the class object like this:

```
import * as Chess from "./../../node_modules/chess.js";

var chess = new Chess();
```

I have not tested it in depth, but I was able to call functions in the class.

Comment: Hey Michael. Figured this might be late & hoping it helps someone in the future.

I wrote the typings file for chess.js but have been too lazy to add it to definitelyTyped (i swear, i will get to it someday)

In the mean time, you can find it here: [Git Repo](https://github.com/Sliverb/angular-firebase-chess/tree/master/src/typings).

Having this in your folder should allow typescript to properly ref the lib, meaning you can go back to using this "import * as Chess from 'chess.js';"